# When i try to node it gives bitfield error how can i solve?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm started to make a bot. But when I try to node, it giving that.

Here is the source code and I tried to solve with intents. I solved one error but it gives bitfield error now.

---

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["BOT"] })

const Token = "censor";



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Agres is online!');
});

client.login(Token);
```

---

```txt
C:\Users\Mustikk\Desktop\Projects\AgresBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:152
    throw new RangeError('BITFIELD_INVALID', bit);
    ^

RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: BOT.
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\Mustikk\Desktop\Projects\AgresBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:152:11)
    at C:\Users\Mustikk\Desktop\Projects\AgresBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:147:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\Mustikk\Desktop\Projects\AgresBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:147:40)
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\Mustikk\Desktop\Projects\AgresBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:546:33)
    at new Client (C:\Users\Mustikk\Desktop\Projects\AgresBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mustikk\Desktop\Projects\AgresBot\bot.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"BOT" isn't an intent. The right way to put intents are like this :

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
```

In discord.js v12, setting intents in Client options is not necessary; you can do it if you want but by default, Discord will just send events for all intents you qualify for (all non-privileged intents + privileged intents you are whitelisted for/enable in the dev portal).

In discord.js v13, you will have to specify the intents you need.

Take a look at the example I gave above, you can use this example for adding the intents you need!

Also, you technically can request all intents with `intents: Discord.Intents.ALL`, however you really should not do this because that removes the whole point of intents; not sending the bot events it doesn't need to reduce bandwidth, CPU, and RAM consumption.

Comment: i tried like u told to me but i took this error

` ` `ReferenceError: Intents is not defined` ` `

Comment: oh i found that on developer portal may this help me `https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents`

Comment: @poemo224 Intents isn't defined because you need to define it with :

```const { Intents } = require('discord.js');```
Define it before `const client`